# Return status outside heredoc in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, heredoc

I have a usecase where i need to get the return status of a nested heredoc and if the command fails then inside heredoc the main shell should exit.

```
ssh username@<ip address> << EOF1
su - user2 << EOF2
 command1 
 check return status if >1 then exit
EOF2
Check return status of EOF2 if >1 then exit
command2
EOF1
```

In this case my script is not able to capture the return code and it is executing command2 even if command1 fails

Is there any possibility to get the return status of the nested heredoc and exit from main shell?

Answer (score 0):

You should exit from `su -` with error, and then run command2 after testing error code.

```
ssh username@<ip address> << EOF1
if  su - user2 << EOF2
    if false; then # Replace [false] with your command1
        echo "Successful from [su]"
    else
        echo "Failed from [su]"
        exit 1
    fi
EOF2
then
    echo Running command2
else
    echo "command1 failed."
fi
EOF1
```